# Find out what makes DBCC CHECKDB makes database offline

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, sql-server-2008, dbcc

We are using DBCC CHECKDB on our database since long. But from past 4-5 days, it makes our database offline.

Our database size is 80GB . The drive where tempdb is located, have free space of 50GB.

We had it online and it recently stopped working that way when database checks happens.

Anybody guide me how we can find out what is the real cause of offline dbcc check.

Comment: What do your error logs say, what does the ouput of DBCC say, and what parameters/options are you passing to the DBCC CHECKDB?

Comment: What stopped working? Are you saying that your database literally goes into an offline state when you run `DBCC CHECKDB`?

Comment: Log says success and it took around 17 min to do the check db. Do we have detailed log and if yes, where to find it/enable it.

Comment: @scsimon it do not stop working actually. It works but now with offline mode without any error. Just need to find out why before it was working online and  now suddenly from past 3 days it does checkdb offline.

Comment: Did you figure out what makes the db go offline?

Comment: Nope, we restored from backup.